# Password protecting individual files

Tags: windows, security, encryption

Im wondering what is the best way to password protect individual files or folders? I am working with peoples personal details and need to secure the currently unprotected files. I was thinking of using something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) but am unsure if this would still protect the files from access while the folder is mounted etc.....any help or advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a truecrypt volume is mounted, any program can read the data. Truecrypt encryption is transparent to programs.

> [Keep in mind, that the content of a mounted TrueCrypt volume is visible (accessible) to all logged on users.](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/)

...

> note that switching users in Windows XP or later (Fast User Switching functionality) does not dismount a successfully mounted TrueCrypt volume

If you really want to encrypt individual files, you could use a program such as [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)